# Why will my UIPickerView only respond when not in a superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm adding a `UIPickerView` to my view when a `UILabel` is tapped. When I was adding the `UIPickerView` by itself, it worked fine:

```
static const CGFloat HMCMeasurePickerHeight = 200.0;
CGRect measurePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       CGRectGetHeight(self.view.window.bounds) - HMCMeasurePickerHeight,
                                       CGRectGetWidth(self.view.window.bounds),
                                       HMCMeasurePickerHeight);
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:measurePickerFrame];
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

However, I wanted a toolbar with it, so I wrapped it in a `UIView`:

```
static const CGFloat HMCMeasurePickerAccessoryHeight = 44.0;
static const CGFloat HMCMeasurePickerHeight = 200.0;
CGRect measurePickerSuperviewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                CGRectGetHeight(self.view.window.bounds) - HMCMeasurePickerHeight - HMCMeasurePickerAccessoryHeight,
                                                CGRectGetWidth(self.view.window.bounds),
                                                HMCMeasurePickerAccessoryHeight);
UIView *measurePicker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:measurePickerSuperviewFrame];
CGRect measurePickerAccessoryFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                0.0,
                                                CGRectGetWidth(self.view.window.bounds),
                                                HMCMeasurePickerAccessoryHeight);
UIToolbar *measurePickerAccessory = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:measurePickerAccessoryFrame];
measurePickerAccessory.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIBarButtonItem *rightAlignSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                     target:nil
                                     action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(dismissMeasurePicker:)];
measurePickerAccessory.items = @[rightAlignSpacer, doneButton];
[measurePicker addSubview:measurePickerAccessory];
CGRect measurePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       HMCMeasurePickerAccessoryHeight,
                                       CGRectGetWidth(self.view.window.bounds),
                                       HMCMeasurePickerHeight);
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:measurePickerFrame];
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[measurePicker addSubview:picker];
[self.view addSubview:measurePicker];
```

Now, when I attempt to scroll the `UIPickerView` nothing happens. I can successfully tap the Done button I added, it's just the `UIPickerView` that is not responding. I tried setting `picker.userInteractionEnabled = YES` but that had no effect (given the first example it seems like it defaults to `YES`).

Comment: I guees the issue is that frame size of measurePicker is smaller than picker. I would suggest you to check on this line. NSLog the final frame of measurePicker and see what width and height it returns.

Comment: You were right! I forgot to add `HMCMeasurePickerHeight` to the superview frame height. Make that an answer so I can select it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is that frame size of
measurePicker is smaller than picker. I
would suggest you to check on this line.
NSLog the final frame of measurePicker
and see what width and height it
returns.